# How to create a sub viewport in html - Blazor

Tags: html, css, blazor, viewport

I'm working on a service that allows a user to dock a component in our WASM Blazor app in a resizeable container like so:

```
<Splitter>
   <SplitterPane>
          @body
   </SplitterPane>
   <SplitterPane Collapsible="true" Collapsed="@isSmallScreen" Min="460px" Size="30%">
      <DockingWindow/>
   </SplitterPane>
<Splitter>
```

where the component they want to dock gets inserted in the DockingWindow.

The issue is that we use @media breakpoints in our components so that they look nice on different screen sizes, so the docked component is sized based off the device size and not the size of the SplitterPane.

Is there a way to wrap DockingWindow in something (other than an iframe) that would, essentially, create a new viewport that was the size of the SplitterPane so that any inner elements that use @media breakpoints would use that new viewport instead of the browser's?

I can't use an iframe because I need the DockingWindow to be able to interact with the same instance of the service that the rest of the app if using.

Comment: Have you considered using `CSS` `variables` instead? You can pass the width and height to the child component which is then passed to `CSS` as a `variable` allowing for dynamic adjustment.

Comment: Thanks for the response. I have not considered using them, because I don't want to change any of the css used in the components. I just want to trick them into thinking the width of the SplitterPane is the device screen size.